# What's the correct way to make a Model that's not a table In Cake 3.0?

Tags: oop, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have some constants and/or functions which don't belong to any particular table and I want to put them in a model so that they are accessible from other models and controllers. How would I do this?

In Cake 2 it was as simple as setting $useTable = false;

Comment: Your question is very vague, please add more detail about the kind of object you are looking for, and the context in wich it is to be used.

Comment: Entity is not type of a model, it is a specific subpart of a Table, representing a part of its rows. So there is only Table actually, which itself is part of "Repository", so anything extending/implementing that can be used. As for your case I suspect you might want to look into [Forms](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html). Often times (like for contact forms) you would want to use that instead.

Comment: I hope my question is less vague after I edited it?

Answer (score 0):

A model less form is the way to process model less data.

[Check the manuals chapter about that.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html)

Comment: A modeless form seems like it is meant for forms (with validation et al). What if I just want a regular model with functions in it that get called by other models and controllers or even by it's own controller but without a form or table?

Comment: Just create your own kind of class then?